# Awk script returning blank output

Tags: awk

Here is the input data save as sample.csv

```
aNumber|bNumber|startDate|timeZone|duration|currencyType|cost|dicatedAccused|balanceAfter|trafficCase|teleServiceCode|location|dataVolume|numberOfEvents|fafIndicator|netWorkID|serviceProvideID|serviceClass|nAno|nBno|bNumberZnCode|fileNamedID|Destination|Operator|unknown3|MainAmount|ReAnalyse|DEDICATEDACCBALBEF|DEDICATEDACCBALAFT|ACCOUNTGROUPID|SERVICEOFFERINGS|SELECTEDCOMMUNITYID|BALANCEBEFORE
22677512549|778|2014-07-02 10:16:35.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|NULL|11.50|0|4|22676020076|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|34|77512549|778|NULL|1131257|OTHER|Short Code|126244088|0.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|11.5000
22675557361|76457227|2014-07-02 10:16:38.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|10.00|NULL|1009.10|0|4|22676613028|NULL|NULL|1|NULL|NULL|35|75557361|76457227|NULL|1131257|Airtel|Airtel|4132206314|10.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|1019.1000
22677521277|778|2014-07-02 10:16:42.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|NULL|0.00|0|4|22676020078|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|34|77521277|778|NULL|1131257|OTHER|Short Code|130071591|0.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|0.0000
22676099496|77250331|2014-07-02 10:16:42.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|1.00|9|0.50|0|4|22676613028|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|35|76099496|77250331|NULL|1131257|Airtel|Airtel|4132218551|0.0000|0|4.0000|3.0000|NULL|NULL|NULL|0.5000
22667222160|22667262389|2014-07-02 10:16:43.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|10.00|NULL|16070.00|0|4|22676613028|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|35|67222160|67262389|NULL|1131257|Airtel|Airtel|4132222628|10.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|16080.0000
22665799922|70110055|2014-07-02 10:16:45.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|20.00|6|0.50|0|4|22676020076|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|35|65799922|70110055|NULL|1131257|Telmob|Telmob|126260244|20.0000|0|44.0000|24.0000|NULL|NULL|NULL|0.5000
22676239633|433|2014-07-02 10:16:48.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|NULL|0.20|0|4|22676020027|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|35|76239633|433|NULL|1131257|Airtel_TollFree|Short Code|397224944|0.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|0.2000
```

I have to group by date,dicatedAccused,trafficCase and teleserviceCode and then based on the result of this group by I have to sum up duration, cost, balanceAfter, MainAmount and Balancebefore. I used a awk script as follow:

Here is the awk script I'm using (saved as test.awk):

```
BEGIN {FS="|"}FNR = 1 {next}{sub(/ .*/,"",$3);key=sprintf("%10s %10s %12s %12s",$3,$8,$10,$11)   duration[key] += $5 cost[key] += $7 bAfter[key] += $9 main[key] += $26 dedAccbBefore[key] += $27 dedAccbAfter[key] += $28 bBefore[key] += $NF}END {printf "%-10s\t\t %10s %12s %12s %10s %10s %10s %10s %12s %12s %10s\n", "date","dAccused","TrafficCase","ServiceCode","Duration","Cost","BalanceAfter","MainAmount","DAcBlBefore","DAcBlAfter","BalanceBefore" 
for (i in duration) { 
printf "%-47s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\t %10s\n", i,duration[i],cost[i],bAfter[i],main[i],dedAccbBefore[i],dedAccbAfter[i],bBefore[i] }}
```

When I run my awk script:

```
$ awk -f test.awk sample.csv
```

The output I have is blank except the header

```
date         dAccused  TrafficCase  ServiceCode   Duration       Cost BalanceAfter MainAmount  DAcBlBefore   DAcBlAfter BalanceBefore
```

I expect the output to be:

```
date       dAccused TrafficCase ServiceCode Duration    Cost    BalanceAfter    MainAmount  DAcBlBefore DAcBlAfter  BalanceBefore   
2014-07-02   6       0           4           0           20      0.5             20             0            44          0.5    
2014-07-02  NULL     0           4           0           10      17090,8         20             0            0          17110,8 
2014-07-02   9       0           4           0            1      0,5             0              0            4           0,5
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with my script please?

Answer (score 1):

Your rule `FNR = 1` is an assignment, not a test, so evaluates to true for every line. You should change it to `FNR == 1`.

Aside from the simple syntax error, your script in its current form produces a lot of syntax errors for me as well, due to the fact that you have a lot of statements on the same line without any `;` separating them. If you are going to use an awk script, as opposed to a one-liner, you should add some newlines in to make your script more readable:

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" }
FNR == 1 { next }
{ 
    sub(/ .*/,"",$3) 
    key=sprintf("%10s %10s %12s %12s",$3,$8,$10,$11)
    duration[key] += $5 
    cost[key] += $7 
    bAfter[key] += $9 
    main[key] += $26 
    dedAccbBefore[key] += $27 
    dedAccbAfter[key] += $28 
    bBefore[key] += $NF
}
END {
    printf "%-10s\t\t %10s %12s %12s %10s %10s %10s %10s %12s %12s %10s\n", 
        "date","dAccused","TrafficCase","ServiceCode","Duration","Cost","BalanceAfter","MainAmount","DAcBlBefore","DAcBlAfter","BalanceBefore" 
    for (i in duration) { 
        printf "%-47s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\t %10s\n", 
            i,duration[i],cost[i],bAfter[i],main[i],dedAccbBefore[i],dedAccbAfter[i],bBefore[i] 
    }
}
```

Here's the output I get, running the above script on your file:

```
$ awk -f test.awk file                                                  
date                       dAccused  TrafficCase  ServiceCode   Duration       Cost BalanceAfter MainAmount  DAcBlBefore   DAcBlAfter BalanceBefore
      NULL          0  22676020027         NULL          0        0.2          4          0          0          0                 0
    0.0000       NULL       0.2000                       0          0          0          0          0          0               0.2
      NULL          0  22676020078         NULL          0          0          4          0          0          0                 0
      NULL          0  22676613028         NULL         21    17079.6         12          4          3          0           17099.6
    0.0000       NULL      11.5000                       0          0          0          0          0          0              11.5
    0.0000       NULL       0.0000                       0          0          0          0          0          0                 0
      NULL          0  22676020076         NULL         20         12          8         44         24          0               0.5
2014-07-02                                               0          0          0          0          0          0             14098
```

Comment: awk: so.awk:10: (FILENAME=TEST.csv FNR=2) fatal: attempt to access field -2 here the error message i got when i changed FNR = 1 to FNR == 1

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I have added the output I get to my answer

Comment: I used the "corrected script" you gave but i have only 0 as returned value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Perhaps you could edit your question to make it clear what output you are getting. Either way, I'm not really sure how to help you further if I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @SPHINX `attempt to access field -2` has nothing to do with `FNR` so changing it hasn't caused this error, it probably just allowed the script to get far enough to fail.

Comment: my script is working fine now but when i tried on over 10 GB file I ain't got no output. So i would like to know: There is a limit amount of input awk can treat ?

Comment: Are you writing output to the terminal here? You may have more success if you split up the file into chunks.